# Orbeon Forms: Extract Form Definition XML via API

Tags: orbeon

I appreciate that this is an odd one..

With our Orbeon integration with another product we dont appear to have an API to extract the XML for our form definitions.

Does Orbeon have standard APIs to do this, or is there another way we could extract the data?

Many thanks in advance..

PeteA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to "extract" an empty XML template of the data from a form definition is to use the [Background API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/other-apis/run-form-background#returning-form-data) ability to return form data, which also allows you to specify the version of the data format you are interested in, with the `data-format-version` request parameter.